# Не могу прочитать js код

Tags: javascript, post, push-уведомления, push

Подскажите пожалуйста , мой сайт использует пуш подписки стороннего сервиса (evadav) , хотел посмотреть код который в подключённом файле , но он оказался зашифрован вот кусок кода -
  `function(){var _0x3b272d=this,_0x3f8228=arguments;return Promise['resolve']()['then'](function(){const _0x3ecaca=_0x572a;return _0x3b272d[_0x3ecaca(0x130)][_0xdb3238][_0x3ecaca(0xe0)](_0x3b272d[_0x3ecaca(0x130)],_0x3f8228),_0x365a1a(_0x3b272d['_request'])[_0x3ecaca(0xc3)](function(_0x1657a3){const _0x1561ed=_0x3ecaca;return _0x1657a3?new _0x117045(_0x1657a3,_0x3b272d[_0x1561ed(0xa1)]):void 0x0;});});});}),_0x301719[_0x482932(0x11c)][_0x482932(0xfc)]=function(){const _0x14ba08=_0x482932;return new _0x7f924c(this['_store'][_0x14ba08(0xfc)][_0x14ba08(0xe0)](this[_0x14ba08(0xb5)],arguments));}`

Подскажите пожалуйста , как его можно расшифровать ?

Comment: А в чем вопрос?

Comment: нужно взять все значения и поочередно подставлять, в итоге выйдет вполне понятный кусок кода.

Comment: Вот к примеру `var _0x3b272d = this` так Вы узнаете что хранится за числом `_0x3b272d` и уже можете востановить часть кода, например дать имя `that` и произвети везде замену, и т.д. Оригинальные имена восстановить нельзя, да собственно для исполнения кода они не так важны.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , буду методично всё заменять )